# Board layout for checkers type game(multiple views on screen, etc)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a checker type game for android. On the screen, there is a board view and a checker piece view. I want the user to be able to drag the checker piece from one part of the screen to another.

Does anyone have suggestions on what's the best layout for this situation?

Right now, I am using a frame layout, and adding the board view and checker piece view as a child.  But I'm not sure if this is the best approach for this problem. The problem that I'm running into is overlaying the board view and the checker piece view. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities.

1)
Using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and handling touches with [android-multitouch-controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/).

2)
If you are doing a game, why don't you use a game framework? Cocos2d would be an excellent option here. I wrote a blogpost about Cocos2d's flavours in android. You can read it [here](http://android-argentina.blogspot.com/2011/01/cocos2ds-android-flavors.html).